# ASP.NET Page.Header.DataBind() automatically triger call to angular service method conflict

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, data-binding

I have a strange problem with ASP.NETmaster page and code behind.
When Page.Header.DataBind() is called somehow all public method on my angular service are called.

Here is my angular service:

```
myModule.service("movimientosService", [
function () {

    function buscarBase(postData){
        alert('why enters here???');
        return "";
    }

    this.buscarMovimientos333 = function(postData){
        return buscarBase(postData);
    }
    }]);
```

Here is ASP code behind whichcause trouble:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e){
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

After Page.Header.DataBind() is executed I can see message box 'why enters here???'
IF I comment out  Page.Header.DataBind() then there is no call to method buscarMovimientos333()
Any idea why?

If I add another method this one will be called as well. Each public method will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was the problem.

Inside controller I mismatch arguments:

```
myModule.controllers.controller('PagoArriendoMainCtrl', 
    ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$q', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $q, aaa, bbb) {

}]);
```

After removing 'ccc' all starting to work as expected.